# Are file access times not properly maintained in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, filesystems, spotlight, timestamp, procmail

I'm trying to determine how file access times are maintained by default in [Mac OS X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X), as I'm trying to diagnose some odd behaviour I'm seeing in a new [MBP Unibody](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro#Unibody_MacBook_Pro) (running Snow Leopard, 10.6.2):

The symptoms (drilling down to the specific behaviour that seems to be causing the issue):

- mutt is unable to switch to mailboxes which have recently received new mail
- mail is delivered by procmail, which updates the mtime of the mbox folder it is updating, but does not alter the atime (this is how new mail detection works: by comparing atime to mtime)
- however, both the [mtime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atime_%28Unix%29) and [atime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atime_%28Unix%29) of the mbox file is getting updated

Through testing, it does not appear that `atimes` can be set separately in the filesystem:

```
: [ether@tequila ~]$; touch test
: [ether@tequila ~]$; touch -m -t 200801010000 test2
: [ether@tequila ~]$; touch -a -t 200801010000 test3
: [ether@tequila ~]$; ls -l test*
-rw-------  1 ether  staff  0 Dec 30 11:42 test
-rw-------  1 ether  staff  0 Jan  1  2008 test2
-rw-------  1 ether  staff  0 Dec 30 11:43 test3
: [ether@tequila ~]$; ls -lu test*
-rw-------  1 ether  staff  0 Dec 30 11:42 test
-rw-------  1 ether  staff  0 Dec 30 11:43 test2
-rw-------  1 ether  staff  0 Dec 30 11:43 test3
```

The test2 file is created with an old `mtime`, and the `atime` is set to now (as it is a new file), which is correct. However, test3 is created with an old `atime`, *but is not set properly on the file*.  To be sure this is not just behaviour seen with new files, let's modify an old file:

```
: [ether@tequila ~]$; touch -a -t 200801010000 test
: [ether@tequila ~]$; ls -l test
-rw-------  1 ether  staff  0 Dec 30 11:42 test
: [ether@tequila ~]$; ls -lu test
-rw-------  1 ether  staff  0 Dec 30 11:45 test
```

So it would seem that atimes cannot be set explicitly (it is always reset to "now" when either `mtime` or `atime` modifications are submitted).

Is this something inherent to the filesystem itself, is it something that can be changed, or am I totally crazy and looking in the wrong place?

PS. the output of `mount` is:

```
: [ether@tequila ~]$; mount
/dev/disk0s2 on / (hfs, local, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
map -hosts on /net (autofs, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_home on /home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
```

...and Disk Utility says that the drive is of type "Mac OS Extended (Journaled)".

Comment: After running the touch command, what does `echo $?` report?

Comment: All commands report $?=0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From `man touch` (on snow leopard):

```
Change the modification time of the file.  The access time of the
file is not changed unless the -a flag is also specified.
```

More importantly, it works fine for me:

```
betelgeuse:tmp james$ touch test
betelgeuse:tmp james$ touch -m -t 200801010000 test2
betelgeuse:tmp james$ touch -a -t 200801010000 test3
betelgeuse:tmp james$ ls -lu test*
-rw-r--r--  1 james  wheel  0 31 Dec 07:41 test
-rw-r--r--  1 james  wheel  0 31 Dec 07:41 test2
-rw-r--r--  1 james  wheel  0  1 Jan  2008 test3
betelgeuse:tmp james$ ls -l test*
-rw-r--r--  1 james  wheel  0 31 Dec 07:41 test
-rw-r--r--  1 james  wheel  0  1 Jan  2008 test2
-rw-r--r--  1 james  wheel  0 31 Dec 07:41 test3
betelgeuse:tmp james$
```

On the other hand, when I try the same thing in ~ I get the same results as you:

```
betelgeuse:~ james$ touch test
betelgeuse:~ james$ touch -m -t 200801010000 test2
betelgeuse:~ james$ touch -a -t 200801010000 test3
betelgeuse:~ james$ ls -lu test*
-rw-r--r--  1 james  staff  0 31 Dec 07:42 test
-rw-r--r--  1 james  staff  0 31 Dec 07:42 test2
-rw-r--r--  1 james  staff  0 31 Dec 07:42 test3
```

The difference? Spotlight doesn't index /tmp, but it does index ~. I'm pretty sure that what you're seeing here is spotlight reading the file to index it after you change the atime - which then sets the atime back to now.

Solution is easy: just add the dirs you don't want indexed to Spotlight's list of folders that shouldn't be indexed.

Just to confirm that this was the case, I made a new dir called "nospotlight" and told Spotlight not to index it.

```
betelgeuse:nospotlight james$ ls -l *
-rw-r--r--  1 james  staff  0 31 Dec 07:47 test
-rw-r--r--  1 james  staff  0  1 Jan  2008 test2
-rw-r--r--  1 james  staff  0 31 Dec 07:47 test3
betelgeuse:nospotlight james$ ls -lu *
-rw-r--r--  1 james  staff  0 31 Dec 07:47 test
-rw-r--r--  1 james  staff  0 31 Dec 07:47 test2
-rw-r--r--  1 james  staff  0  1 Jan  2008 test3
```

Give Spotlight permission to index it, and mere seconds later:

```
betelgeuse:nospotlight james$ ls -lu *
-rw-r--r--  1 james  staff  0 31 Dec 07:48 test
-rw-r--r--  1 james  staff  0 31 Dec 07:48 test2
-rw-r--r--  1 james  staff  0 31 Dec 07:48 test3
```

and once again, modifying the mtime results in an updated atime.

It's definitely Spotlight.

Comment: Confirmed! atime is left alone if mail/ is added to Spotlight's "Privacy" list, and mutt/procmail work as expected.  I'm dismayed that Spotlight doesn't know well enough to fix the atime -- otherwise it rather defeats the purpose of having an atime to begin with. :(

Comment: Well, it did alert you to the fact that something was snooping through your mutt folders :p